# Mouse sluggish/choppy

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, touchpad, trackpad

So I have a Macbook 6,1 running Linux Mint 17 x64 Qiana (based on Ubuntu 14.04) using MATE with Compiz and I am having random mouse slow downs (only when using the trackpad).

It happens randomly and requires a reboot to fix. It makes my mouse choppy and less responsive. If I click on something and don't touch the trackpad it won't register till I move the cursor, also if I take my finger off the trackpad and put it back on to adjust it the cursor will teleport in that direction.

On earlier installs this problem was solved using this solution (https://superuser.com/questions/528727/how-do-i-solve-periodic-mouse-lag-on-linux-mint-mate) but it doesn't seem to have any effect on later versions of Mint/Ubuntu.

Does anybody know how to fix this by chance?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem with an Acer TimelineX and Linux Mint 17.
My mouse is a Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000. The suggested fix did not work as well.

This might sound too easy but have you ever tried another USB-Port?
I always connected it to an USB 3.0 Port and then I tried another(USB 2.0).

It seems now the problem is gone.

Comment: Playing a flash video, in one Chrome window, having gmail open in another Chrome window and moving the mouse over Google Maps in another Window with dual screen and open source ATI drivers makes my Logitech M705 very laggy. I tried both USB 2 and USB 3 ports on the back of my computer but it made no difference. Using the front panel USB 2 or USB 1 ports seems to solve it though. Could the more clear path be the reason?... Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Seems like this is a comment. I've tried 9 different ports and experienced the same behavior. Seems to be the traffic from another peripheral in my case.

Comment: I had a headphone dongle right next to my mouse dongle. Moving the mouse dongle fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my very weird case : a "power bank" charging caused the behaviour you describe.
But the effect was not immediate : only after, say, one hour of connexion, things became sluggish. (which made it hrd to figure out)
Unplug, and voilà, solved. 
Very strange.